# Python 3 Type Hints with Forward Reference and Proper Inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, type-hinting

Working with Python 3.6 under Win10x64 in PyCharm 2017.

I know typing (or even type hinting) is kind of unpopular in the Python community, but please bear with me.

Let's say I have a `Node` class to create tree-like containers with arbitrary contents. Here is a highly simplified version:

```
from typing import Any, List

class Node:

    def __init__(self, content: Any, parent: 'Node' = None):
        self.content = content  # type: Any
        self.parent = parent  # type: 'Node'
        self.children = []  # type: List['Node']
        if parent:
            parent.children.append(self)

    @property
    def descendants(self) -> List['Node']:
        """Returns a list of nodes that are descendant from the node starting with its first child, then its
            descendants (and ending with the last descendant of its last child)."""
        out = []
        for ch in self.children:
            out.append(ch)
            for desc in ch.descendants:
                out.append(desc)
        return out
```

I am trying to use proper type hints. Seeing as I need to indicate the type of `parent` to be `Node`, I used the quotes as prescribed in [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references) for forward references. Same with `self.children`, using `List['Node']`, and also with the property `descendants`.

If I inherit from Node (like so `class SpecialNode(Node): pass`), I would expect PyCharm's type checker to be able to infer all the relevant types correctly, such that `SpecialNode` is expected in place of `Node`.

Consider this:

```
n_root = Node('foo')
n_0 = Node(10, parent=n_root)
n_01 = Node('bar', parent=n_0)
n_root_and_children = [n_root] + n_root.children
n_root_and_descendants = [n_root] + n_root.descendants

s_root = SpecialNode('special_foo')
s_0 = Node(-10, parent=s_root)
s_01 = Node('special_bar', parent=s_0)
s_root_and_children = [s_root] + s_root.children
s_root_and_descendants = [s_root] + s_root.descendants
```

Obviously all of this still "works" at runtime, but PyCharm underlines `s_root.descendants` in the last line and tells me:

**Expected type 'List[SpecialNode]' (matched generic type 'List[TypeVar('_T')]'), got 'List[Node]' instead**

What am I doing wrong?

.

**EDIT:**

Inspired by an answer that is now deleted, I figured out the solution using `TypeVar`, but do not fully understand, why it works. I would appreciate, if anyone could answer this better.

```
from typing import Any, List, TypeVar

NodeType = TypeVar('Node')


class Node:

    def __init__(self, content: Any, parent: NodeType = None):
        self.content = content  # type: Any
        self.parent = parent  # type: NodeType
        self.children = []  # type: List[NodeType]
        if parent:
            parent.children.append(self)

    @property
    def descendants(self) -> List[NodeType]:
        """Returns a list of nodes that are descendant from the node starting with its first child, then its
            descendants (and ending with the last descendant of its last child)."""
        out = []
        for ch in self.children:
            out.append(ch)
            for desc in ch.descendants:
                out.append(desc)
        return out


class SpecialNode(Node):
    pass


n_root = Node('foo')
n_0 = Node(10, parent=n_root)
n_01 = Node('bar', parent=n_0)
n_root_and_children = [n_root] + n_root.children
n_root_and_descendants = [n_root] + n_root.descendants

s_root = SpecialNode('special_foo')
s_0 = Node(-10, parent=s_root)
s_01 = Node('special_bar', parent=s_0)
s_root_and_children = [s_root] + s_root.children
s_root_and_descendants = [s_root] + s_root.descendants
```

PyCharm leaves me alone and the code works properly.

Comment: check out this related question for forward referencing (and accepted answer) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33837918/type-hints-solve-circular-dependency.
It also states that python 3.7+ has a cleaner solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to your edit, it looks like PyCharm is doing its own thing because `mypy` does not like this code:

```
(mytest) bash-3.2$ mypy test2.py
test2.py:5: error: String argument 1 'Node' to TypeVar(...) does not match variable name 'NodeType'
test2.py:5: error: "object" not callable
test2.py:10: error: Invalid type "test2.NodeType"
test2.py:12: error: Invalid type "test2.NodeType"
test2.py:13: error: Invalid type "test2.NodeType"
test2.py:15: error: NodeType? has no attribute "children"
test2.py:18: error: Invalid type "test2.NodeType"
test2.py:22: error: Need type annotation for 'ch'
(mytest) bash-3.2$
```

This is on `mypy 0.641` and `Python 3.7.1`.

Have you revisited this edit/fix since?