# How to avoid a NameError when making an alias to annotation type using circular reference?

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, type-hinting

As [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33844891/2520359) suggests, from Python 3.7 onward it's possible to use forward declarations in type annotations if the

```py
from __future__ import annotations
```

instruction is used.

However, this still doesn't work if I want to create an alias for the annotation type:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
import typing

MyType1 = typing.Union[str, MyType2]
MyType2 = typing.Mapping[str, MyType1]
```

This still gives me `NameError: name 'MyType2' is not defined`

I know about the fallback syntax using string literals, and it does work. However, I'm curious whether it's somehow possible to use the formally available new approach.

Answer (score 3):

One technique is to use the [`typing.TYPE_CHECKING` constant](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING). This constant is always false at runtime, but is treated as if it were always true by type checkers such as mypy:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Union, Mapping
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    MyType1 = Union[str, MyType2]
    MyType2 = Mapping[str, MyType1]
```

Since this constant is False at runtime, Python will never try evaluating either type alias, which lets you dodge the NameError.

You'll need to either use the `from __future__ import annotations` directive or use string literal types whenever you use either type hint though, of course.