# Type hint for two classes that have themselves as element from two diferent files

Tags: python, type-hinting

I have two classes from two different files.

I want to use type hints to make it easier to use.

```py
from b import ClassB

# a.py
class ClassA():
    b: ClassB
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = None
```

```py
from a import ClassA

# b.py
class ClassB():
    a: ClassA
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = None
```

But I run into a circular dependency problem

this doesn't work either because `ClassA` is not defined in this file

```py
# b.py
class ClassB():
    a: "ClassA"
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = None
```

Comment: Or rather this: [Type hints: solve circular dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33837918/type-hints-solve-circular-dependency)

Comment: I'm not sure what [from \_\_future\_\_ import annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61544854/from-future-import-annotations) is supposed to have to do with this.