# How to provide type annotations in case of circular dependency in different files in Python?

Tags: python, type-hinting, circular-dependency, forward-declaration

Please consider the following working code

```
from __future__ import annotations


class A(object):
    def __init__(self, val: int):
        self.val = val

    @property
    def b(self) -> B:
        return B(self)


class B(object):
    def __init__(self, a: A):
        self.a = a


a = A(val=1)
print(a.b.a.val)
```

Which only works when both classes are defined within the same file.
output: `1`

---

I want to put each class in a different file, and doing it like so:

file `uv_dataset.cvbnhxx.b2`:

```
from uv_dataset.cvbnhxx.a2 import A


class B(object):
    def __init__(self, a: A):
        self.a = a
```

file `uv_dataset.cvbnhxx.a2`:

```
from uv_dataset.cvbnhxx.b2 import B


class A(object):
    def __init__(self, val: int):
        self.val = val

    @property
    def b(self) -> B:
        return B(self)


a = A(val=1)
print(a.b.a.val)
```

now gives

`ImportError: cannot import name 'B' from partially initialized module 'uv_dataset.cvbnhxx.b2' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/noam.s/src/uv_metadata/uv_dataset/cvbnhxx/b2.py)`

---

How to make circular annotations resolve properly? I was not able to do it correctly with [forward declaration](https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references), but likely because I got the syntax wrong.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33844891/913098) doesn't work for multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to module-only imports and forward-references should work as the [documentation](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#forward-references) says.

First have a directory structure similar to the following.

```
foo/
  __init__.py
  a.py
  b.py
```

`a.py` and `b.py` import each others module but not the class and `__init__.py` imports from a and b

`__init__.py`

```
from foo.a import A
from foo.b import B
```

`a.py`

```
from foo import b


class A(object):
    def __init__(self, val: int):
        self.val = val

    @property
    def b(self) -> 'b.B':
        return b.B(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A(val=1)
    print(a.b.a.val)
```

`b.py`

```
from foo import a


class B(object):
    def __init__(self, a: 'a.A'):
        self.a = a
```

Comment: I am still getting the circular error in my actual code. Can you please show how this should be done in case the file hierarchy is more than one level deep?

Comment: I am getting the error on the init file

Comment: @Gulzar do you have a and b in the `uv_dataset.cvbnhxx` module/folder? If so you should change the imports similar to `from uv_dataset.cvbnhxx.a import A` in `__init__.py` and `from uv_dataset.cvbnhxx import a` in a/b

Comment: I have the imports in the init as you wrote (importing the class) and in the files, importing the files. Even with the imports commented out in the files, I am getting the circular dependency in the init file. Can you show please how to do it correctly when the imports arise from different folders? The file running everything is a different one than the file defining a is a different from the one defining b. Assume everything is in its own directory structure.

Comment: Sorry for it getting complicated, I didn't expect this.

Comment: Which init should the imports go into?

Comment: @Gulzar I would have thought `uv_dataset.cvbnhxx.__init__.py`

Comment: I will have to get back to it and accept when I have more time. For now I will have to leave it untyped. Thanks!

Comment: Any chance the class and file being named exactly the same cause problems? When putting the imports in the correct init it starts failing only when importing the class from a different file