# NameError: name 'Class_Name' is not defined

Tags: python, class, structure, nameerror

I have an issue which is I keep getting the error of NameError: name 'Class_Name' is not defined. Which I understand. The tricky part is that my code looks something like this:

```
class FirstClass():
  second_class: SecondClass
  def __init__(self):
      """SOME CODE HERE"""

class SecondClass(firsClass: FirstClass):
  def __init__(self):
      self.first_class = firstClass
```

So the problem is that no matter how I arrange the code, I will always have one above the other so it will always say that is not defined. How can I solve this?

------------------------**SOLUTION**----------------------------

I found the solution to this. If you use the import

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

It will read the file and you will be able to call the classes even if they are defined later in the code.

Comment: Is this a learning exercise? Because you should never write classes like this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type hints: solve circular dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33837918/type-hints-solve-circular-dependency)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found the solution to this.

If we use the import
`from __future__ import annotations`
it will read the file and it won't have that problem, so we can reference different things in the order that we want. Taking the example:

```
class FirstClass():
  second_class: SecondClass
  def __init__(self):
      """SOME CODE HERE"""

class SecondClass(firsClass: FirstClass):
  def __init__(self):
      self.first_class = firstClass
```

This will be resolved as:

```
from __future__ import annotations

class FirstClass():
  second_class: SecondClass
  def __init__(self):
      """SOME CODE HERE"""

class SecondClass(firsClass: FirstClass):
  def __init__(self):
      self.first_class = firstClass
```

You can find more details in the python documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html

Answer (score 0):

```
from pprint import pp

class FirstClass():

  #for typing, if you want to indicate a class variable
  second_class: type["SecondClass"]

  #for typing, if you want to indicate an instance variable
  second_class_instance: "SecondClass"

  def __init__(self):
      """SOME CODE HERE"""

      self.second_class_instance = self.second_class()

#this looks off in the inheritance declaration - dont specify types here
#class SecondClass(firsClass: FirstClass):

class SecondClass(FirstClass):
  def __init__(self):
      #this code will error, watch your cases!
      #self.first_class = firstClass
      ...

#for doing something with the second_class attribute, later in the runtime
#however, no tricks with "SecondClass" quoting allowed, you need
#to wait till both FirstClass and SecondClass EXIST, which is why 
#this line is here, with this indentation
FirstClass.second_class = SecondClass

first = FirstClass()
pp(first)
pp(vars(first))
```

Is doing this a good idea?  **Probably not**, but may there is special, special, justification for tracking a `second_class` class reference, say to call a class constructor without hardcoding the SecondClass in FirstClass methods.

And, in this scheme, I am even less convinced by having SecondClass subclass FirstClass, but...

#### output:

```
% py test_429_declare.py
<__main__.FirstClass object at 0x10841f220>
{'second_class_instance': <__main__.SecondClass object at 0x10841f250>}
```

and `mypy`

```
% mypy test_429_declare.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Comment: Actually, I found the solution for this. If we use the import
`from __future__ import annotations` it will read the file and it won't have that problem, so we can reference different things in the order that we want.

Comment: @Reponic if you fixed with that approach, you should probably post it, and accept it, as an answer instead of a comment in your Q.

Comment: Will do! Thanks for the reminder